# StackOverflowError when operating with a large number of columns in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, mapreduce, apache-spark-sql, stack-overflow

I have a wide dataframe (130000 rows x 8700 columns) and when I try to sum all columns I´m getting the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
>       at scala.collection.generic.Growable$$anonfun$$plus$plus$eq$1.apply(Growable.scala:59)
>       at scala.collection.generic.Growable$$anonfun$$plus$plus$eq$1.apply(Growable.scala:59)
>       at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
>       at scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray.foreach(WrappedArray.scala:35)
>       at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:59)
>       at scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ListBuffer.scala:183)
>       at scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ListBuffer.scala:45)
>       at scala.collection.generic.GenericCompanion.apply(GenericCompanion.scala:49)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.BinaryExpression.children(Expression.scala:400)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.containsChild$lzycompute(TreeNode.scala:88)
>   ...

This is my Scala code:

```
  val df = spark.read
    .option("header", "false")
    .option("delimiter", "\t")
    .option("inferSchema", "true")
    .csv("D:\\Documents\\Trabajo\\Fábregas\\matrizLuna\\matrizRelativa")


  val arrayList = df.drop("cups").columns
  var colsList = List[Column]()
  arrayList.foreach { c => colsList :+= col(c) }

  val df_suma = df.withColumn("consumo_total", colsList.reduce(_ + _))
```

If I do the same with a few columns it works fine but I´m always getting the same error when i try the reduce operation with a high number of columns.

Can anyone suggest how can I do it? is there any limitation on the number of columns?

Thx!

Comment: Have you tried increasing your stack size?

Comment: What are the job configurations that you're running with, like the number of executors provided, cores and memory provided to the executors.

Comment: @ErnestKiwele im using Intellij in a 16GB RAM laptop for local executions with JVM options -Xmx12288m -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit.

Comment: @SivaprasannaSethuraman in cluster mode executions with 64 cores and 64 GB RAM I´m using the following parameters:                                                                   
spark-submit --class es.upo.datalab.entrypoints.testDR.Test_dataset_dr_2016 --master mesos://10.141.0.224:7077 --deploy-mode cluster --executor-memory 55G --total-executor-cores 60 hdfs://hidra.lsi.us.es:9000/fabregas/jars/test_dataset_dr_2016_2.11-2.0.0.jar

Comment: @JoseAntonioFabregas The parameter for stack size is `-Xss`. Try `-Xss1M` or something larger to see. Just remember to send that JVM option to all your workers, such as with `--conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Xss1M"` on spark-submit call

Comment: Have you tried with the foldLeft? instead of reduce

Comment: @ShankarKoirala I think that the `foldLeft` would also produce the same linear chain of `BinaryExpression`s, and it would also blow the stack.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use a different reduction method that produces a balanced binary tree of depth `O(log(n))` instead of a degenerate linearized `BinaryExpression` chain of depth `O(n)`:

```
def balancedReduce[X](list: List[X])(op: (X, X) => X): X = list match {
  case Nil => throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot reduce empty list")
  case List(x) => x
  case xs => {
    val n = xs.size
    val (as, bs) = list.splitAt(n / 2)
    op(balancedReduce(as)(op), balancedReduce(bs)(op))
  }
}
```

Now in your code, you can replace

```
colsList.reduce(_ + _)
```

by

```
balancedReduce(colsList)(_ + _)
```

A little example to further illustrate what happens with the `BinaryExpression`s,  compilable without any dependencies:

```
sealed trait FormalExpr
case class BinOp(left: FormalExpr, right: FormalExpr) extends FormalExpr {
  override def toString: String = {
    val lStr = left.toString.split("\n").map("  " + _).mkString("\n")
    val rStr = right.toString.split("\n").map("  " + _).mkString("\n")
    return s"BinOp(\n${lStr}\n${rStr}\n)"
  }
}
case object Leaf extends FormalExpr

val leafs = List.fill[FormalExpr](16){Leaf}

println(leafs.reduce(BinOp(_, _)))
println(balancedReduce(leafs)(BinOp(_, _)))
```

This is what the ordinary `reduce` does (and this is what essentially happens in your code):

```
BinOp(
  BinOp(
    BinOp(
      BinOp(
        BinOp(
          BinOp(
            BinOp(
              BinOp(
                BinOp(
                  BinOp(
                    BinOp(
                      BinOp(
                        BinOp(
                          BinOp(
                            BinOp(
                              Leaf
                              Leaf
                            )
                            Leaf
                          )
                          Leaf
                        )
                        Leaf
                      )
                      Leaf
                    )
                    Leaf
                  )
                  Leaf
                )
                Leaf
              )
              Leaf
            )
            Leaf
          )
          Leaf
        )
        Leaf
      )
      Leaf
    )
    Leaf
  )
  Leaf
)
```

This is what `balancedReduce` produces:

```
BinOp(
  BinOp(
    BinOp(
      BinOp(
        Leaf
        Leaf
      )
      BinOp(
        Leaf
        Leaf
      )
    )
    BinOp(
      BinOp(
        Leaf
        Leaf
      )
      BinOp(
        Leaf
        Leaf
      )
    )
  )
  BinOp(
    BinOp(
      BinOp(
        Leaf
        Leaf
      )
      BinOp(
        Leaf
        Leaf
      )
    )
    BinOp(
      BinOp(
        Leaf
        Leaf
      )
      BinOp(
        Leaf
        Leaf
      )
    )
  )
)
```

The linearized chain is of length `O(n)`, and when Catalyst is trying to evaluate it, it blows the stack. This should not happen with the flat tree of depth `O(log(n))`.

And while we are talking about asymptotic runtimes: why are you appending to a mutable `colsList`? This needs `O(n^2)` time. Why not simply call `toList` on the output of `.columns`?

Comment: Nice effort and great answer :)

Comment: I followed your advice calling `toList` on the output of `.columns` and getting a List of Columns with `map(col)` for `reduce`. Then, I used your `balancedReduce` method and it works great.

Thank you!