# How to resolve Apache Spark StackOverflowError after multiple unions

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have a Spark Scala program which uses a REST API to get data batch by batch, and once all the data is retrieved I operate on them.

**Current Program:**

- For each batch, create RDD and merge it with the previous RDD
  created using the previous API call `rdd.union(currentRdd)`.
- Operate on final RDD

A simple program to reproduce the issue:

```
    def main(args: Array[String]) = {
     val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Union test").setMaster("local[1]")
     val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
     val limit = 1000;
     var rdd = sc.emptyRDD[Int]
     for (x <- 1 to limit) {
       val currentRdd = sc.parallelize(x to x + 3)
       rdd = rdd.union(currentRdd)
     }
     println(rdd.sum())
   }
```

**Problem:**
- When number of batches are high the program throws a `StackOverflowError` : `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.UnionRDD$$anonfun$1.apply`

I assume, that when the number of batches increases the RDD dependency graph becomes really complex and throwing the error.

What is the best way to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is already [`SparkContext.union`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.SparkContext@union[T](rdds:Seq[org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[T]])(implicitevidence$6:scala.reflect.ClassTag[T]):org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[T]) that knows how to properly compute a `union` of multiple `RDD`s:

```
val rdds = List.tabulate(limit + 1)(x => sc.parallelize(x to x + 3))
val rdd = sc.union(rdds)
```

Alternatively, you could try using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49691021/stackoverflowerror-when-operating-with-a-large-number-of-columns-in-spark/49693374#49693374) helper function to avoid the creation of a long chain of `union`s:

```
val rdds = List.tabulate(limit + 1)(x => sc.parallelize(x to x + 3))
val rdd = balancedReduce(rdds)(_ union _)
```

The reason why it should work is essentially the same as in the linked answer: `O(n)` chain of `union`s blows the stack, `O(log(n))`-high binary tree of `union`s doesn't.